# ASP MVC3 - Editor Template returning null values to controller on post back

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, mvc-editor-templates, icollection

I've been struggling with a project for a couple days now, and in my current iteration I've decided to use an Editor Template.

The original issue arose from a master table linked to a secondary table via a foreign key in SQL. In ASP MVC, the secondary table is being represented with the following field:

```
    [UIHint("BankListAgentId")]
    public virtual ICollection<BankListAgentId> BankListAgentId { get; set; }
```

Because this is a collection object, the `GET` on the "Edit" page works for each particular item, however on the `POSTBACK` all the collection items are suddenly null. All other fields carry the proper data, however. I am trying to use and editor template, however the collection items are still being returned `null`.

Here is the code I am using in the view

```
@model Monet.Models.BankListMaster
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Stat(s) Fixed</legend>
        <table id="fixedRows">
            <tr>
                <th>State Code</th>
                <th>Agent ID</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            
            @foreach (var item in Model.BankListAgentId)
            {                    
                
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.AgentId) && item.FixedOrVariable.Equals("Fixed"))
                {
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => item)                     
                    
                }
            }
        </table>
        <br />
        @Html.ActionLink("Add another", "BlankFixedRow", null, null, new { id = "addFixed" })
    </fieldset>
}
```

And here is the editor template. It's name is `BankListAgentId` and sits in a folder named `EditorTemplates` in the Views folder
[image]

```
@model Monet.Models.BankListAgentId

    <tr id="item-@Model.AgentId">
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StateCode,
                (SelectList)ViewBag.StateCodeList, Model.StateCode)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AgentId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AgentId)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a>
        </td>
        @*<td><a href="#" onclick="$('#item-@Model.AgentId').parent().remove();" style="float:right;">Delete</a></td>*@
    </tr>
```

Here is the code from the `BankListMaster` model

```
public partial class BankListMaster
{
    public BankListMaster()
    {
        this.BankListStateCode = new HashSet<BankListStateCode>();
        this.BankListAgentId = new HashSet<BankListAgentId>();
        this.BankListAttachments = new HashSet<BankListAttachments>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string BankName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BankListStateCode> BankListStateCode { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BankListAttachments> BankListAttachments { get; set; }

    [UIHint("BankListAgentId")]
    public virtual ICollection<BankListAgentId> BankListAgentId { get; set; }
}
```

And finally here is the `BankListAgentId` model

```
public partial class BankListAgentId
{
    public string AgentId { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FixedOrVariable { get; set; }
    public string StateCode { get; set; }

    public virtual BankListMaster BankListMaster { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT

The user will need to be able to dynamically alter the list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this as an iteration over the collection rather than a foreach in order for the field names to bind correctly.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.BankListAgentId.Count; i++)
            {                    
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.BankListAgentId[i].AgentId) && Model.BankListAgentId[i].FixedOrVariable.Equals("Fixed"))
                {
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.BankListAgentId[i])
                }
            }
```

You should post your receiving ActionResult too.

P.S. But as DaveA correctly points out the model is ICollection, which will cause issues. Can it not be IEnumerable?

Comment: index for an ICollection? That would break runtime.

Comment: I don't think IEnumerable can index either. Would have to use IList. The only potential problem is if NealR needs to use foreach

Comment: Would this solution allow for the user to dynamically add to the list?

Comment: No, that would be down to you to create those operations through AJAX or similar to iteratively build that collection on the fly as the user adds new elements to that list. I did something similar recently adding children to a Childcare application.

Comment: I added an edit to the post, but that is part of the requirement of this page.